# Google Datastore Modeling - "Chat to Many - with individual last activity time"?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, data-modeling, google-cloud-datastore

I have a Google App Engine application that enables two users to start a ChatSession with each other. Each time they send a message to each other I update an entity holding a LastActivity value, which is the time of when the ChatSession had its last activity.

This was fine because only chat messages between two given users would result in an update of that LastActivity entity.

However now I am trying to implement af "Send same message to multiple users"-feature. And I would still like the LastActivity entity to be updated for each of the ChatSessions. Now it could potentially be many users trying to update the same LastActivity entity. And in my performance tests I begin to see failing transactions, due to the 1 write per second limitation on entities.

So my question is: How would you model "Chat to Many" feature and be able to keep the option to see when the two users have had their last interaction with each other?

In the end I would like to query: Give me all the ChatSessions a given user participates in were there have been activity within the last 24 hours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I thought of two possible solutions.

**Solution 1: Multiple LastActivity entities, not sharing an entity group**

Rather than multiple users sharing a single LastActivity entity, each ChatSession could have multiple LastActivity entities associated with it, one for each user in the chat.

```
class LastActivity(ndb.Model):
    user_id = ndb.IntegerProperty()
    chat_id = ndb.IntegerProperty()
    time = ndb.DateTimeProperty()
```

When you wish to retrieve the information for a user, you could do a query on LastActivity with an inequality that retrieves those in the last 24 hours.

If you are careful not to use child entities, then they will not be part of the same entity group and won't be subject to contention.

**Solution 1 - Edit**

To get a list of all the chat sessions a user participated in the last 24 hours, you could do:

```
one_day_ago = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
chats = LastActivity.query(LastActivity.user_id == user_id, LastActivity.time > one_day_ago).fetch()
for chat in chats:
    # Do something with chat.chat_id
```

**Solution 2: Task Queue**

Use the Task Queue to update the LastActivity value. If the task fails due to contention, it will use exponential back-off and try again.

Comment: Thanks @Milo, I am now trying with solution 1. I have added an additional property named 'participants' to LastActivity, which contains a list of the two participant ids. Hence I can query give me all LastActivity where participants == 'the requesting user's id' and then order by time in descending order. Is this what you meant with solution one? Or are you able to make that same query without the additional 'participants' property? - I am also in doubt, how would you do pagination with this approach? I have tried using Cursors, but I don't think it suits this case. Have you any suggestions?

Comment: Thanks. Rather than making user_id (participants) a list, I envisioned keeping each LastActivity entity unique to one user. That way you will never get contention, caused by multiple users trying to update the entity at the same time. I've updated my answer to show how I would query it. I've never needed to paginate NDB results before, so I haven't used Cursors myself. However, when I read the documentation it seemed a good solution. What makes you think it doesn't suit this case?